# Storage account name already taken after being deleted from another tenant

Tags: azure, azure-storage-account

I want to delete some of my Azure resources from my current tenant to create them on another tenant. However, I cannot recreate the storage accounts on the new tenant, since I keep getting this error: "The storage account name '<name>' is already taken."

I'm aware that storage account names must be globally unique; however, they have been deleted from the old tenant for more than three days, so the name should be available. Note that Azure does allow me to recreate them on the *same* tenant, so I assume Azure is holding on to the deleted storage accounts in some way. Is there a way of forcing Azure to "release" the deleted storage accounts?

**Update**: I checked again. Storage accounts that had been deleted on 1 July could be recreated on the new tenant by 11 July, whilst those deleted on 5 July could only be recreated on 13 July, so it takes **7–8 days** for the names to be released.

Comment: You have to wait until it's finally deleted. The clean up of some resource might last a day

Comment: It looks deleted from the old tenant (doesn't show up in the portal or `Get-AzStorageAccount`). It's been more than three days.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. You should post it as an answer to your own question :)

Answer (score 3):

If I'm correct the default retention for Storage accounts is actually 14 days, which is the period one would use to recover deleted accounts.

You can use the Recovery procedure to detect if your recently deleted storage account is still in "recycle". read more at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-recover

Comment: The document also mentions the following: `A new storage account with the same name has not been created since the original account was deleted.`. This tells me that it is possible to create an account with the same name after it has been deleted.

Comment: To my knowledge this only works when attempting to re-create a storage account you just deleted ("in-place"), or restore it.

Comment: This is correct. You can reuse it immediately in the current tenant but must wait up to 14 days (or when the garbage collector finally deletes the storage account and frees up the domain).  

Marius is suggesting to use the recovery procedure to see if it's still listed as recoverable as if it shows up the domain is still being held.