# StorageAccountAlreadyTaken - but for how long?

Tags: azure, azure-storage-account

I created a **Storage Account** in one Azure subscription, I deleted the storage account, and now I am trying to create a new **Storage Account** in another Azure subscription with the same name, but I get the error **StorageAccountAlreadyTaken**.

The documentation states the following:

- The name must be globally unique
- A deleted storage account can be recovered in up to 14 days unless the name has been taken by another storage account

As I read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-recover) I should pretty much immediately be able to create a storage account with the same name somewhere else. It has been three days now, and I can still not create a storage account with the same name in another Azure subscription.

What are your experiences with this, is the name really locked for 14 days?

Comment: I saw a similar question a few days ago - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72867938/storage-account-name-already-taken-after-being-deleted-from-another-tenant though I do not agree with the answer there. You may want to reach out to Azure Support.

Comment: Azure Support...... that contact has to go through our administrators, and they usually take 14 days to answer if at all... But thanks for the relevant post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that between tenents one can expect **7-8 days** according to this other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72867938/storage-account-name-already-taken-after-being-deleted-from-another-tenant), while it is almost instant within a tenent. I suspect that the roof is **14 days** then.